# PM2 not showing Express app in browser

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I am using [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) in my [Express](http://expressjs.com/) app for process management and load balancing. I have just installed the PM2 and given the command `pm2 start bin/www`
this command works in command prompt, it is showing the result like this:

[image: 3]]

This is fine now I am opening the web browser and accessing the application as usual `localhost:3000` but it is not opening the application its is showing **ok** in the browser.

What could be the possible reason? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: can you restart your app using pm2 restart bin/ww

Comment: pm2 restart bin/www --name arpit-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. We know when we create an app using Express (Express generator) it creates all the folder and places `app.js` file in the root folder. For some reason, I kept the app.js file inside a folder and changed its path in `bin/www` file. It was working perfectly when I was running `npm start` but with PM2 it was now opening the application in the browser. So I again placed the `app.js` file in the root folder and now it is working fine.